# understand the output of stty -a and change ctrl backspace to just backspace

Tags: bash, cygwin, stty

I am working in bash shell on a **Solaris** environment and whenever I type "backspace" it clears out the entire line.

Do you have any suggestions for me to change the backspace clearing entire line to just a character which is the expected behavior of it?

Hhow do I interpret the output of `stty -a` command in my local **cygwin** environment:

```
$ stty -a <br/>
speed 38400 baud; rows 34; columns 125; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = ^Z; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -tostop echoctl echoke
```

Answer (score 2):

From the wording of your question, I'm assuming that you're using cygwin to access a Solaris machine.

`stty -a` displays all the current settings for the terminal. I won't go through each one. But you can read up on what each one does on the [man pages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/stty-1.html).

But of particular note to your problem is `erase = ^?;`. `^?` is the [ASCII Control Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII) for `DEL` (delete). What you want is the control character for `BS` (backspace).

From the command line you can type the following:

`stty erase ^H`

But note that the `^H` is a control character and not <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>. So I believe the way that you would type this is as follows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd>

And that should result in `^H` being printed to the screen.

That should change the behavior of <kbd>backspace</kbd> to what you want. But it would only last for the current session.

According to [this Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dmick/entry/making_backspace_be_your_default), you can permanently change the configuration by opening `/kernel/drv/options.conf` and looking for the following line:

`ttymodes="2502:1805:bd:8a3b:3:1c:7f:15:4:0:0:0:11:13:1a:19:12:f:17:16";`

Change the `7f` to `8` to permanently remap <kbd>backspace</kbd> from `DEL` to `BS`. This will require a reboot to take effect.